# How to put PDO bindParam in if statement?

Tags: php, if-statement, pdo

How to put PDO bindParam in if statement? I tried to do a different variations, but none of them worked.

```
function get_all_pages($subject_id, $public = true)
    {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=name;charset=utf8', 'root', 'whatewer');
    $query = "SELECT * ";
    $query.= "FROM pages ";
    $query.= "WHERE subject_id =:id ";
    if ($public)
        {
        $query.= " AND visible =:visible ";
        }

    $query.= "ORDER BY position ASC";
    $query.= "ORDER BY position ASC";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    if ($public)
        {
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $subject_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':visile', 2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        }
      else
        {
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $subject_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        }

    $stmt->execute();
    $affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
    if ($affected_rows == 1)
        {
        $subject = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $subject;
        }
    }
  else
    {
    return null;
    }
}
```

Ok there was misunderstanding I got my cod "Wright" it was stackoverflow that messed my code up. i was struggling to put  code in code area. In reality it looks like this.

http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/593/zvf8.png

Comment: That looks ok to me (if I've read through the messy indentation correctly), except that you have `ORDER BY position ASC` _twice_.  Debug it with `echo $query` and you'll see what is being passed to `prepare()`.

Comment: Also you have no param named `:visile` which you are trying to bind to...

Comment: This query will have `ORDER BY position ASCORDER BY position ASC` at the end...

Comment: Errors are your friend. this looks like it was coded blind then slapped up here for us to troubleshoot for you.

Comment: To start ... after trying to edit I realized your code have wrong braces, the last `else` matches no opening brace. I think the closing brace after the first `if($public)` shouldn't be there or something.

Comment: Use `$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=name;charset=utf8', 'root', 'whatewer', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));` and see what errors you get.

Comment: @grap please do not edit your OP based on answers. That makes them obsolete.

Comment: Grap, I got sidetracked in a discussion with qwertynl, for which I appologize.  Is your issue resolved? If not, can you turn on error reporting as @jeroen suggested and let us know what the output is please?  You may need to `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` for them to display in the browser.

Comment: @jeroen its not resolved last night i struggled for hours Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();` might give you unexpected results as according to the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php):

> For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the
>   number of rows affected by a SELECT statement.

You should fetch a row directly and see what the result is:

```
$stmt->execute();
if ($subject = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    return $subject;
}
else
{
    return null;
}
```

And I would recommend opening your database connection as I mentioned in my comment:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=name;charset=utf8', 'root',
              'whatewer', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));
```

That will cause PDO to throw exceptions and that will give you a clear error message whenever something goes wrong on any of the db calls.

Comment: thanks for helping, but still nothing. Throws me the same error. Mybe this will help. Prefiusly i used this function,but i need to bind parameters right? `function get_all_pages($subject, $public = true){
 $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_name;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
 $query = "SELECT * ";
 $query .= "FROM pages ";
 $query .= "WHERE subject_id ={$subject} ";
 if($public){
  $query .= " AND visible = 2 ";
 }
 $query .= "ORDER BY position ASC";
 $stmt = $db->query($query);
 return $stmt;
}`

Comment: @grab Turn on error display and let PDO throw exceptions. And if previousely you returned `$stmt` you should do that now as well.

Comment: Thank problem solved. The problem was, that i needed to return $stmt instead of $subject.